# GIT, How to apply a bugfix in a rebase workflow

Tags: git, workflow, rebase

We're using git, feature branches and rebase to bring the feature branches to our master. So our graph looks like this

```
* 08a3854 - (master, Feature_2) implement feature_2 more
* cf944c7 -                     implement feature_2 ...
* 4b4ed7c - (Feature_1)         implement feature_1 more
* 483fd88 -                     implement feature_1 ...
```

If we now detect a bug in Feature_1 (and this feature is not so old) we would fix the feature directly on that point. First we're creating a branch from Feature_1 for bugfixing.

```
* 08a3854 - (master, Feature_2) implement feature_2 more
* cf944c7 -                     implement feature_2 ...
| * 2c383b6 - (Feature_1_fix)   fix for feature_1
|/  
* 4b4ed7c - (Feature_1)         implement feature_1 more
* 483fd88 -                     implement feature_1 ...
```

At the end we would like to bring the Feature_1_fix branch into Feature_1 branch and delete the fix branch afterwards so that the result might look like this.

```
* 08a3854 - (master, Feature_2) implement feature_2 more
* cf944c7 -                     implement feature_2 ...
* 2c383b6 - (Feature_1)         fix for feature_1
* 4b4ed7c -                     implement feature_1 more
* 483fd88 -                     implement feature_1 ...
```

Is it possible and what do we have to do?

Answer (score 0):

In a way it is theoretically possible but you definitely don't want to do that.

Every commit's hash is dependent on all its ancestors. If you change a commit, all child commits' hash values will change. In that sense your third example graph is wrong: commits cf944c7 and 08a3854 will change.

Maybe you heard of the mantra: Don't rebase a pushed branch. In order to achieve what you want, you'd have to rebase master onto feature_1_fix. Any work that depends on the current master will have to get rebased as well.

```
08a3854   * (old obsolete master) implement_feature_2 more
cf944c7   *                       implement feature_2
2222222 * | (master)              implement_feature_2 more
1111111 */                        implement feature_2
2c383b6 *   (Feature_1)           fix for feature_1
4b4ed7c *                         implement feature_1 more
483fd88 *                         implement feature_1
```

Commits 1111111 and 2222222 are new and everybody who based work on 08a3854 has to rebase that work onto 2222222 as well.

By the way: git doesn't allow you to push something like this without explicitly specifying the `--force` flag.

I'd suggest to simply create the branch and merge it. I also wouldn't necessarily recommend basing the fix branch directly on the last commit of the feature. If you have a lot of changes, merging it into the current master may result in a lot of conflicts.